# LPR print, can it be directly to printer?

Tags: debian, printing, cups, lpr, lpd

I have a USB printer, connected to a network print server (TL-PS310U).

I want to print from Debian/Ubuntu to this printer. The queue is named `2409ee3c`, but when I try to use `lpr`, it says that I need to add `/version=1.1`:

```
user@user:~$ lpr -H 192.168.100.1 -P prt0 C0003022.che.spl 
lpr: Error - add '/version=1.1' to server name.
```

Then I added the printer in CUPS (http://localhost:631) as `lpd`, with name `Printserver`:

`lpd://192.168.2.30/2409ee3c`

And I now can print with LPR:

```
user@user:/run/shm$ export CUPS_SERVER=localhost:631; lpr -H 192.168.2.30 -P 2409ee3c C0003022.che.spl 
lpr: The printer or class does not exist.
jsivil@jsivil:/run/shm$ export CUPS_SERVER=localhost:631; lpr -H 127.0.0.1 -P Printserver C0003022.che.spl
```

My questions are:

1) Can I print with LPR directly to this printer behind a printserver? (I've tried `netcat` but it doesn't work for this printserver)

2) Does LPR need CUPS? Is it OK to use 127.0.0.1?

3) How can I avoid having to export the CUPS_SERVER variable prior to use `lpr`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`netcat` could be used, though you'd need to send appropriate LPD commands over it. [rlpr](http://linuxfocus.org/~guido/endangered_software.html#rlpr) is doubtless a better option for direct printing than figuring out how to do RFC 1179 over `netcat`.

The CUPS `lpr` client does need a CUPS server, as the CUPS server does the heavy work, and the client portion is mostly just a compatibility shim for the traditional `lpr` or `lp` command line interfaces.

CUPS has a `~/.cups` configuration directory that might be used instead of an environment variable, though I do not recall needing to set `CUPS_SERVER` where the print server was on the local system:

```
% ls ~/.cups/           
lpoptions
% cat ~/.cups/lpoptions          
Default ps307g
%
```

Comment: I didn't know of `rlpr`, seems to do the job. Thanks